# How to connect Azure data bricks cluster from VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, databricks

I have a Cluster to run notebook and libraries but I need to connect VM from this cluster.

How do I set up Azure data bricks from VM machine

Comment: Connect other Azure VM from Azure databricks, or connect VMs behind databricks?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I have modified the question. Kindly check that is possible to connect Azure Databricks cluster from VM machine?

Comment: I understand what you want . But we cannot achieve this for now. Due to the NSG and whole resource group are locked to Ready-Only, we cannot set up connection to the data cluster. Including from an Azure VM.

Comment: How to achieve this? Is there any other option

Comment: There is not  any option to achieve this for now.

Comment: Can I use curl by submitting like job from outside - Passing parameter as cluster-Id